# Button as HyperlinkButton

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-store-apps

Instead of creating a HyperlinkButton to navigate to other page in a frame, i want to use the Button. I have this HyperlinkButton

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/MyPageName" TargetName="mainFrame" Content="Go To My Page" />
```

i think it is possible and i have this so far

```
<Button x:Name="btnView" Content="View">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <!-- and i dont know what is next here -->
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

any help would be aprreciated..

TIA

Comment: Why are you not creating custom style button that look like HyperlinkButton or are you facing problem for navigation ?

Comment: Im facing problem for navigation not the design of the button @Xyroid

Comment: why are you not using `Button`'s click event ? You can navigate with this `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPageName));` [WinRT XAML Navigating from Page to Page](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-navigating-from-page-to-page-how-it-differs-from-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 0):

Design the contents of the HyperlinkButton.

```
<HyperlinkButton Name="btn" Margin="340,5,0,0" Background="Transparent" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="2,0,2,2" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="110">
  <HyperlinkButton.Content>
    <Grid>
      <Rectangle Fill="#FFC1B7B7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Stroke="#FF1D1212" StrokeThickness="2" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" />
      <TextBlock Text="NONE" FontSize="16" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="tb" Padding="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="110" FontFamily="Courier New" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
  </HyperlinkButton.Content>
</HyperlinkButton>
```